# FCM Notification are not showing in foreground in android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Notifications are showing in the background but when the app is in the foreground notifications are not showing. I applied many solutions but they do not work for me. Can anyone tell me where is my mistake? thanks in advance

**Here is Manifest**

```
        <service
        android:exported="false"
        android:name=".services.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/cute" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/design_default_color_on_primary" />
```

**Here is My ServicesClass**

```
const val cannelId = "notification_channel"
const val channel_name = "com.dextrologix.dham.rfms.resident.services"
class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        if (remoteMessage.notification != null) {

            genrateNotification(
                remoteMessage.notification!!.title!!,
                remoteMessage.notification!!.body!!
            )
        }
    }
    @SuppressLint("RemoteViewLayout")
    fun getRemoteView(title: String, message: String): RemoteViews {
        val remteViews = RemoteViews(
            "com.dextrologix.dham.rfms.resident.services",
            R.layout.pushnotification_layout
        )
        remteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_title, title)
        remteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.notification_message, message)
        remteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.notification_image, R.drawable.cute)
        return remteViews
    }
    fun genrateNotification(title: String, message: String) {
        var intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
        var builder: NotificationCompat.Builder =
            NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, cannelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.person_icon)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000))
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        builder = builder.setContent(getRemoteView(title, message))
        val notificationManager =
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationChannel =
                NotificationChannel(cannelId, channel_name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
        }
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build())

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are missing notification channel. They are required for android notifications.
[docs link](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have edited my code but it still not working in foreground

Comment: Are there any errors? Can you double check your google_services.json?

Comment: no there is no error. when I add debugger or toast  in  onMessageReceived()  nothing show .. I think my function is not called anywhere

Comment: It is not, but it listens for the push from FCM. Are you sure that you have googleServices.json in the right place and it is configured correctly? If not it should show waкnings in logcat, something like googleServices not found/not configured etc